# pass by reference an object in a static function C++?

Tags: function, static, pass-by-reference

Can static functions have pointers as parameters?

For example this code:

```
static void myFunctionName(Object &object1)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, it's a reference, not a pointer. But aside from this, a static method can have any parameter that would be legal for a non-static function. There is no difference between the two in that aspect.